# Including DLL in C# Class Library

Tags: c#, class-library

I want to reference/include and C++ dll file in to my C# class libary, with a normal C# windows form I just put the dll in the working directory, this does not seem to work for class libraries, how do I get it to find the .dll?

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("ve.dll", EntryPoint=<MethodName>, CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

That is the call to the methods and the DLL I am including is in the build folder.

Comment: You put it in the directory with the DLL and reference the path (relative or absolute) in the `DllImport` attribute. Can you define "doesn't work"?

Comment: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("ve.dll", EntryPoint="<MethodName>", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

That is the call to the functions, and by dosn't work I get the error "Unable to Load "ve.dll" when I run the program.

Comment: As far as I can tell that should work. Have you checked the DLL with dumpbin /exports

Comment: in the build folder for the library? or the hosting exe?

Comment: Also if you have 64bit machine it will default to a 64bit application. Is the DLL 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: @jbriggs Build folder for the library, and I know the dll works and all the functions are correct, I am able to use it fine when I make it as a C# windows form

Comment: @jbriggs The DLL is 64bits, but I have used it fine before, its just now when I am making a class liabry instead of a windows form that it can not be referenced.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. The answer I provided below is a copy from working code with the dll name changed and the function name changed only

Answer (score 2):

You may need a post-build step to ensure that the DLL is copied to your build output folder when you recompile the application. Once that's done, the `DLLImport` attribute should be able to find the DLL using the short name of the file, without any path information (since it will be local to the executing assembly).

Comment: I tend to prefer to add the dll to the project (not as a reference just as a file) and then set CopyLocal to true.

Comment: @JamesBarrass Essentially the same thing. I believe that has what boils down to the same effect--although potentially with some folder wonkiness. You should make that an answer, though. I'd give you the vote for it, since I'd forgotten that.

Answer (score 2):

The c++ dll needs to be either local to the hosting exe (if the hosting exe references the c# dll it will copy that local to itself on build) or in a location in the system PATH environment variable.

You can add the c++ dll to the c# project (Add ->Existing Item -> All Files) and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` or `Copy Always` and set `Build Action` to `None` (IIRC the default option)

Comment: I believe you also need to set the Build Action to none

Comment: @Lawtonj94 After Add Existing Item... you don't see the dll listed in your solution explorer?

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't a managed DLL then you need to use the DllImport attribute. Assuming the DLL has exported functions. You can check the exported function names using *dumpbin /exports*

```
private const string DLLPATH = "MyDLL.dll";

[DllImport(DLLPATH, EntryPoint = "GetDLLStatus")]
public static extern int GetDLLStatus();

[DllImport(DLLPATH, EntryPoint = "SomeOtherFunction")]
public static extern float SomeOtherFunction();
```

DllImport will first look for the DLL in the application directory then look in your path

Comment: I already have that, since its in the build folder I assume the path does not need anything extra just the dll name.

Comment: Correct. If it is in the build folder it shouldn't use the path. Is your c# library compiled as 64bit? or AnyCpu? and the Application?

Comment: When you say build folder you are talking about the application directory right? Not the C# library output directory